# ¿Como puedo deshabilitar los puntos '.' y comas ',' en una entrada de texto?

Tags: javascript, html

Saludos, necesito que en una entrada de texto (text input) como:

```
<input type="text" id="txtNombre" name="txtNombre" value="" placeholder="Ej: Juan" required="" />
```

no me deje colocar '**.**' y '**,**'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En vanilla JS:

```js
function noPuntoComa( event ) {
  
    var e = event || window.event;
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if ( key === 110 || key === 190 || key === 188 ) {     
        
       e.preventDefault();     
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="noPuntoComa( event )">
```

Desglose [`KeyCode`](https://salinasjavi.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/codigos-javascript-del-teclado-keycodes/):

- `110` - Punto en el teclado izquierdo
- `190` - Punto en el teclado derecho
- `188` - Coma

Comment: En Chrome funciona pero en Firefox da error: `event is not defined`. ¿Sabes porque no funciona `event` en Firefox?

Comment: @blonfu - Ya lo he arreglado y mejorado.. probado en FF y Chrome... falto pasar el evento y usar e.preventDefault() en vez de [returnValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/returnValue) que está despreciado.. gracias por el aviso

Answer (score 1):

Buenas amigo puedes usar la libreria [Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) y pesarle como parámetro una expresión regular.

**Expresión regular**

```
/[^.,]/
```

Esta expresión nos indica que puedes ingresar cualquier carácter menos el `.` y la `,`

**Ejemplo funcional**

```js
$("#txtNombre").mask('ZZ',{translation:  {'Z': {pattern: /[^.,]/, recursive: true}}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.13/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtNombre" name="txtNombre" value="" placeholder="Ej: Juan" required="" />
```

Espero sea lo que buscas saludos.